# Add an array into another array if certain indexes match php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an two arrays in php, what i would like to do is if drug_ids match, I want to add the second array as a sub array.
What I have

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [drug_id] => 1
            [drug] => Abacavir 300mg - Tabs
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [drug_id] => 4
            [drug] => Abacavir/Lamivudine 120/60mg - FDC Tabs
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [drug_id] => 3
            [drug] => Abacavir/Lamivudine 600/300mg - FDC Tabs
        )
);
```

The second array with more data

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [decision_date] => 2018-08-10
            [discussion] => The product is at 2.6 MOS
            [recommendation] => recommendation
            [drug_id] => 1
            [created] => 2018-08-16 09:23:09
            [user] => System Admin
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [decision_date] => 2018-08-10
            [discussion] => recommendation.
            [recommendation] =>recommendation.
            [drug_id] => 4
            [created] => 2018-08-16 09:23:09
            [user] => System Admin
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [decision_date] => 2018-08-10
            [discussion] => The product is at 6MOS.
            [recommendation] =>ggfgfg.
            [drug_id] => 4
            [created] => 2018-08-16 09:23:09
            [user] => System Admin
        )
);
```

I would like to push the second array into the first one as decisions if drug ids match to create a final array

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [drug_id] => 4
            [drug] => Abacavir/Lamivudine 120/60mg - FDC Tabs
            [decisions] => Array(
                  [0] => Array
                            (
                             [id] => 3
                             [decision_date] => 2018-08-10
                             [discussion] => recommendation.
                             [recommendation] =>recommendation.
                             [drug_id] => 4
                             [created] => 2018-08-16 09:23:09
                             [user] => System Admin
                            )

                  [1] => Array
                            (
                             [id] => 4
                             [decision_date] => 2018-08-10
                             [discussion] => The product is at 6MOS.
                             [recommendation] =>ggfgfg.
                             [drug_id] => 4
                             [created] => 2018-08-16 09:23:09
                             [user] => System Admin
                            )

            )
        )
```

Any suggestions as to how this can be achieved?

What i have tried
   $table_data //first array
    $table_data //second array

```
foreach ($table_data as $mt) {
                foreach ($items as $it) {
                    if ($it['drug_id'] == $mt['drug_id']) {
                        $decision['decisions'] = $it;
                        array_push($table_data, $decision);
                    }
                }
            }
```

//This does not work

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  Using `foreach()` loops and matching the two sets of values together?

Comment: This is very common task. Try something and then, if you have any issues, we'll help you to resolve them

Comment: @NikitaLeshchev and Ren please see the edit of what I have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug. Try the following

```
foreach ($table_data as &$mt) {
    foreach ($items as $it) {
        if ($it['drug_id'] == $mt['drug_id']) {
            if (!isset($mt['decisions'])) {
                $mt['decisions'] = [];
            }
            $mt['decisions'][] = $it;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
foreach ($arr1 as &$a) {
    $a["decisions"] = array_filter($arr2, function ($b) use ($a) {
        return $b["drug_id"] === $a["drug_id"];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommended nested loops they will do too many unnecessary iterations.  Instead, because the drug_ids in the first array are unique, copy them to be the first level's keys -- this will let you swiftly associate data between the two arrays. When the loop is done, you can remove the first level keys with `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Q1DXl))

```
$drugs = array_column($array1, null, 'drug_id');
foreach ($array2 as $row) {
    if (isset($drugs[$row['drug_id']])) {
        $drugs[$row['drug_id']]['decisions'][] = $row;
    }
}
var_export(array_values($drugs));
```